# Opaque Type with Class

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, opaque-result-type

**A/c to Apple Doc,**

> A function or method with an opaque return type hides its return value’s type information. Instead of providing a concrete type as the function’s return type, the return value is described in terms of the protocols it supports

EDIT: Cutting the whole question short

```
/* PROTOCOLS  */
protocol MyPros {}

/* STRUCT */
struct MyStruct {}

/* CLASSES */
class ClassA : MyPros {}
class ClassB : ClassA {}
class ClassC : ClassB {}
```

Now I using Opaque return type, 1. with struct 2. with class

```
/* FUNCTIONS */

func getOpaqueStruct() -> some MyStruct { // ERROR: An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class
    return MyStruct()
}

func getOpaqueClass() -> some ClassC {
    return ClassC()
}
```

`getOpaqueStruct` returns error which is understandable, if you check `getOpaqueClass` , getOpaqueClass also not returning **protocols, and/or a base class** so why class object able to return any class object in the inheritance chain. It also must be returns the baseclass i.e. classA or protocol i.e. MyPros.

`ClassC` can be in future be superclass of ClassD but base class of these chain is `ClassA`.

Comment: Can you show the method that's not working?

Comment: @Sweeper Please check code, I have added code and comment.

Comment: Your code compiles, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry if I confused you. In struct I can't use `some Earth` but with class I can use `some Earth`. As both are opaque types, so why it is returnable as class not in struct. Thats the only reason I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what the phrase "base class" in the error message means. It doesn't mean "a class that doesn't inherit from anything, and can have subclasses".  It just means "a class that can have subclasses" or in other words, "a class that other classes can inherit from".

Why only limit the feature to classes that doesn't inherit from anything, when anything that could have subclasses can benefit from this feature.

---

Old answer (to revision 3 of the question):

You can't do `some StructType` because structs don't have subclasses. They whole point of opaque return types is to allow you to tell the caller that:

> I'm returning a definite type, but you don't need to know what type this is. You just need to know it is a subclass of `XXXClass`/confomer of `YYYProtocol`.

No other types can inherit from structs, so if you have a method that is said to return `some StructType`, then it can *only* return `StructType`, nothing else. This defeats the purpose of opaque return types.

From the name of your method, writing:

```
func getPlanet() -> some Planet {
    return Earth(name: "Earth", creatures: "Humans")
}
```

would make more sense in my opinion.

The caller knows that `getPlanet` will return a definite type, that is a conformer of `Planet`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The thing I was trying to understand is same thing with the class variable. Two days of understanding from blogs and docs its blows off my head. The points you explained with the `struct` is all valid (No Doubt). Lets assume I have a **class A superclass of B and which is super class of C**. If I returns **some C** you won't thing compiler must have to give error as `C is not a base class` bcz same error it gives if I returns `some myStruct`.

Comment: Except above everything I did with struct I got same behaviour with class like I can not return multple types that conform the base protocol.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand what you are saying here. I _think_ you are asking "Why can I still use `some ClassType` even if `ClassType` does not have subclasses?" Well, the point is not about whether it does/does not have subclasses. It's about whether it _can/cannot_ have subclasses. A class that does not have subclasses _now_ could have subclasses in the future, but a struct can never ever have subclasses. @dahiya_boy

Comment: Can I rephase my question? Points you commented no ever I found so I wanted to know (little bit)  hope you dont mind

Comment: @dahiya_boy Do you mean you want to edit your question because everything I said was things that you already know, and I didn't actually answer your intended question? Ok, you can do that, but make sure you make it clear what you are asking. I am finding it a bit hard to understand you.

Comment: I tried to re-write the question. Try to compare the struct some return type with class return type. I am guessing somewhere you answer be related to the above comments and answer. But I wanted to confirm bcz I dont wanted to keep unbaked knowledge

Comment: @dahiya_boy See the edited answer. Now it just seems like a misunderstanding of the term "base class".

Comment: Thnks buddy, I am feeling you are a detective and solved a mystery for me where I unable to understand who killed whom 